# How to use IPA \textraiserevglotstop on Overleaf?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, arabic, tipa

I am trying to write the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) equivalent of the Arabic letter `ص`, which is `sˤ`, in a LaTeX text using Overleaf, but it does not show the symbol `ˤ`. How to address this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `s\textsuperscript{\textrevglotstop}` or `s\super{\textrevglotstop}`, and it seems that it works almost fine.

Comment: According to section A.3 of the `tipa` manual, this is the correct way. No `\textraiserevglotstop` command exists.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, but it still a large raised symbol. Please see [this](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xunicode-symbols.pdf) table (I know it is not `tipa`)